# How would I create a news system?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a database where I can create a news article through PHPMyAdmin with the fields: "Name of the article", "Content", "Writer".

I have already made a "latest news" system, which looks like this:

```
         $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news LIMIT 5");  

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{ 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['Namn'];
  echo " av ";
  echo $row['Skribent'];
  echo "<br />";

  }
} 
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

And that is the latest news system (skribent means = writer), (namn means = name (of the article), (av means = by),.

So, now I have two problems. Once these news are displayed, I want them to be clickable and once you click it, you get to the original page where the article is located, how do I do it?

And, how do I do so that when I insert a query it will automatically create a nice page for every article, like most famous sites have. When they create a news it comes like http://google.com/news/how-to-be-a-dork/

Comment: Have you done any other work other than just this piece of php? Please show it here? Also if you want to create a news system from scratch you have to come up with better questions than this one.

Comment: Well, I'm not good at PHP, same with SQL. I thought it'd be pretty easy to make one.. I'm sorry.

Comment: You mean a blog? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-an-object-oriented-blog-using-php/ might be useful to you...

Comment: or just install wordpress ;-)

Comment: @etbal - really no need for your hostility. The guy is keen to learn. We don't need people like you being all pretentious and arrogant.

Comment: sorry did not mean to be hostile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly to link articles to a different page you could use the element's onclick method, and use javascript to redirect the user, or you could add `<a>` tag around the article element.

Secondly, if you would like pretty urls you will have to read up on url re-writing, I unfortunately don't know much about it.